# Sourceforge Tickets into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, issue-tracking, sourceforge, ticket-system

In github there is a plugin for importing the tickets (issues) into eclipse, Is there a similar plugin for sourceforge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is with [Eclipse Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)? They have a [big list of extensions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/Extensions) to connect task repositories. Maybe [this one](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/Extensions#CollabNet_TeamForge.2C_formerly_SourceForge_Enterprise_Edition) is what you need?

Comment: I don't mind any tool at all, Just mylyn seemed a bit complex and actually didn't get the chance to go through it, but after your reply i guess I will now thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Mylyn Web Template Connector.  I posted details of getting it to work with SourceForge (Allura) at http://officefloor.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/allura-sourceforge-mylyn-connector/